# what is the best (one with the tightest bounds) concentration inequality for a continuous random variable whose mean and max value is given?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

what is the best (one with the tightest bounds) concentration inequality for a continuous random variable whose mean and max value is given? The random variable can take negative values.

Comment: Even if you're also given the minimum, I'm not sure you can actually do any better than Chebyshev's inequality, because the standard example for which Chebyshev is tight can be arbitrarily well approximated by continuous random variables. (Unless "concentration inequality" means something different than I think it means. I assume it means $P(|X-\mu|>\epsilon)<\delta$.)

Comment: If the minimum was given I would know the maximum value of the variance and chebyshev would become applicable. yes, thats what i mean by concentration inequality.

Comment: So you're going for something *weaker* than Chebyshev? Chebyshev is already generally regarded as uselessly weak.

Comment: No, chebyshev is good enough. I cant figure out how to actually apply it to this problem since I am not sure about the maximum value the variance can take

Comment: You wind up needing something weaker than Chebyshev because the variance in this situation can be arbitrarily large. In the discrete setting, you can choose a variable with mean zero which is always equal to either $-M,0$ or $1$. This means $P(X=-M)=p/M,P(X=1)=p,P(X=0)=1-p(1+1/M)$ where $p$ is the one remaining free parameter and can be used to tune $\sigma/M$. In the continuous setting you need to smear it out but you can do arbitrarily little smearing to obtain essentially the same result.

Comment: Thanks anyways, Ian

Answer (score 0):

By scaling and translation, one can assume that the mean is zero and the max is $1$ (unless the distribution is degenerate). Having done so, splitting the variable into positive and negative parts allows you to apply Markov's inequality to see $P(X \leq -a) \leq \frac{P(X>0)}{a}$ for $a>0$ (since the negative part of $X$ has expectation at most $P(X>0)$.) This then translates into a bound on $P(|X| \geq a)$ once $a>1$. You can then undo the scaling and translation to return to the general case.

Is that the best you can do? Yes: one can look at a variable which is $-a$ with probability $1/a$ and $1$ with probability $1-1/a$ to see that. The continuous aspect does not diminish this, since one can mollify this example arbitrarily little to obtain a continuous example with arbitrarily similar properties.